# What `+` and `-` means in background jobs output

Tags: background-process

When I run a bunch of background jobs with

```
for s in {1,2,3}; do command_$s &; done;
```

I can see all of them with the `jobs` command

```
$ jobs
[2]    running    command_1
[3]  - running    command_2
[4]  + running    command_3
```

I know that the first column is the ID (I can for example `kill -9 %2` to kill `command_`)

But what does `+`, `-` and lack of any of those means? Running `man jobs` and `jobs -h` does not work.

Comment: The man page for your shell will tell you this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Info manual for bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html), there is a description in chapter 7.1, Job Control Basics:

> Job number n may be referred to as ‘%n’. The symbols ‘%%’ and ‘%+’
>   refer to the shell’s notion of the current job, which is the last job
>   stopped while it was in the foreground or started in the background. A
>   single ‘%’ (with no accompanying job specification) also refers to the
>   current job. The previous job may be referenced using ‘%-’. If there
>   is only a single job, ‘%+’ and ‘%-’ can both be used to refer to that
>   job.
>
> In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the `jobs` command),
>   the current job is always flagged with a ‘+’, and the previous job
>   with a ‘-’.